# ¿Cúal método equivalente de ngOnInit en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Estoy empezando a construir una App en flutter, tengo experiencia en Angular he estado buscando información acerca de cuál es el método que se carga inicialmente en flutter, esto lo hago ya que estoy autentificando con usuario y contraseña con Ldap, cosa que ya pude realizar, pero deseo mantener contraseña/usuario con shared_preferences, lo que deseo realizar es que se salten a la pantalla inicial/home si es que ya existe registro del usuario/contraseña y en dado caso que no, o el usuario cierre sesión, este limpie las preferencias y pueda ingresar otro usuario para realizar el loggin, para ello quisiera validarlo en el primer método de carga en flutter, he buscado pero no he encontrado algo para poder realizarlo

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso algo que me funcionó fue verificar la sesión en un **SplashScreen**: se trata de un **widget** que por medio de su propio método `initState()` realiza la consulta al proveedor (ya sea un servicio, un sQLite o un **PreferenceStorage**), y dependiendo la respuesta puedes direccionar al **widget** de login o a la pantalla principal (home), el **widget** de **SplashScreen** es de uso común y sería el primero en ser cargado al iniciar la aplicación. Este mecanismo puede variar dependiendo del patrón que estés usando, pero el flujo es el mismo.

Comment: Lo que estaba pensando era algo así: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359706/flutter-route-into-different-pages-according-to-different-status

Comment: Es una solución, tomando en cuenta que la consulta al storage local es inmediata no se compromete el performance de la App